How do I use a text string in a cell to indicate the sheet in a formula?
I'm doing a COUNTIF and when I auto-fill the formula I'd like the sheet referred to for the range to change based on a text string in a cell. For example I could do this:




A
B
C




1
Sheet
Critical
Moderate


2
Sheet 2
=COUNTIF('Sheet 2'!B:B,B$1)



3
Sheet 3




4
Sheet 4





But I would like to be able to reference A2 as a text string and have the formula take that input to use as the sheet for the COUNTIF range. I've tried what seemed obvious to me:
=COUNTIF('A2'!B:B,B$1) and =COUNTIF('TEXT(A2)'!B:B,Sheet1!B$1)
Have not had any luck figuring it out so thought I would check in here.

You're looking for INDIRECT.

Thank you, I must be missing something with INDIRECT could you elaborate?

Unfortunately that documentation hasn't helped answer the question, that's why I asked.

You could try: =COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&$A2&"'!B2:B100"),B$1)

Of course, adding in the "'" makes all the difference. I'll give it a try thank you.

Yes, that because you have spaces for your sheetnames. Otherwise, its not needed.
